# I have a problem with particle in the box

Tags: plotting

I have a problem while generating particle in the box from this equation

```
Plot[Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n Pi x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]
```

because Mathematica might confuse about my parameter, how can I notice that L is a function of x?

I want my graph have two y axis as a boundary of the box.

Comment: Try `L = 1;
psi[n_, x_] := Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n Pi x/L];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[psi[n, x]^2, {n, 1, 3}]], {x, 0, L}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> True]`

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary values for L and n

```
L = 100;
n = 0.2;
```

Define the function and plot (I assumed you wanted a Frame based on the "two y axis" comment).

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n Pi x/L];
Plot[f[x], {x, -L/2, L/2}, Frame -> True, AxesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed]]
```

[image]